# Why does KDEPIM add “pbecbengr-rivy-znaqngrq-ba” to the domain part of outgoing Message-ID headers?

Tags: email, kmail

When I send an eMail with Kontact (KDEPIM), my `Message-ID` headers look like this:

```
Message-ID: <1548233.Ax4hfq5P2Q@pbecbengr-rivy-znaqngrq-ba.tglase.lan.tarent.de>
```

In contrast, my regular MUA uses:

```
Message-ID: <alpine.DEB.2.11.1408151037370.23325@tglase.lan.tarent.de>
```

So, why does KMail not use just the FQDN of my host, and why does it use the string “pbecbengr-rivy-znaqngrq-ba” (which is [rot13](http://catb.org/jargon/html/R/rot13.html) for “corporate-evil-mandated-on”)? Duckduckgoïng and googling for either string does not yield anything informative or at all…

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my machines.  Who built/packaged your installation of kmail?  I'm building my from KDE's git, and it does not do this.

Comment: Oh okay… this is Debian’s 4.11 (on x32) from unstable, although 4.12 (when I was still running i386) also did this.

Comment: Message-ID: <8988368.jUmubmy0Nr@pbecbengr-rivy-znaqngrq-ba.tglase.lan.tarent.de>
User-Agent: KMail/4.14 (Linux/3.14-2-amd64; KDE/4.14.0; x86_64; ; )

Comment: Still cant reproduce.  My kmail: `Message-ID: <1607262.zf0EqVXt1d@convect>` and `User-Agent: KMail/4.14 (Linux/3.12.13-gentoo-convect-systemd; KDE/4.14.0; x86_64; git-8c495f4; 2014-08-31)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Args. Apparently, this has been written into my `~/.kde/share/config/kmail2rc` under `[Composer]` ⇒ `myMessageIdSuffix`, which I could then backtrace to the “Headers” tab of the “Composer” group of “Settings → Co̲nfigure KMail…”.

Now, the only remaining question is, who has set it there, why, and how. But I guess this answers the initial question I had, and un-checking the “U̲se custom message-id suffix” box helped. (Funnily enough, the Message-ID suffix is normally set under Identities → Advanced…)